# Change the json output?

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

How do I fix the json encode that I have made?

my actual code

```
foreach ($list->result_array() as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $data[] = $val;
    }
}
$output = array(
    "data" => $data,
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Actual output:

```
{"data":["X1.1",2,2,2,3,1,4,"X1.2",1,1,1,1,2,3,"X1.3",2,3,1,2,2,5,"X1.4",2,2,2,3,5,6]}
```

And this is output I need:

```
{"data":["X1.1",2,2,2,3,1,4],["X1.2",1,1,1,1,2,3],["X1.3",2,3,1,2,2,5],["X1.4",2,2,2,3,5,6]}
```

How to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding the data into a single `$data` array. You need to aggregate them separately then put them into a parent array. To get the expected output:

```php
$output = array(
    'data' => array(),
);
foreach ($list->result_array() as $row) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        $data[] = $val;
    }
    $output['data'][] = $data; // aggregate them here
}
echo json_encode($output);
```